# convert uint32 into readable values

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct, dbus

Hello I am writing an API to communicate with the network manager on ubuntu. When I ask for the IP address the dbus service return something like :

```
broadcast_add = dbus.UInt32(4278298816L, variant_level=1)
```

What I am doing so far is converting it to 32 bit binary by :

```
In [1]: '{0:0<32}'.format(bin(broadcast_add)[2:])
Out[1]: '11111111000000011010100011000000'
```

Is there any straightforward way to convert this uint32 to readable ip address like

```
192.168.1.255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access this value `4278298816`, you might try to use [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), for example:

```
>>> import struct
>>>
>>> struct.unpack('<BBBB', struct.pack('<I', 4278298816))
(192, 168, 1, 255)
>>>
>>> '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(*_)
'192.168.1.255'
>>>
```